# What are the valid instanceState's for the Amazon EC2 API?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

What are the valid instanceState's for the Amazon EC2 API? It doesn't seem to be defined in the current [API doc](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/DeveloperGuide/ApiReference-SOAP-DescribeInstances.html). Google doesn't turn up much. So far I know about:

- 0: pending
- 16: running
- 32: shutting-down
- 48: terminated

but I'm pretty sure I've seen an `error` state before.

Thanks!

Comment: here is the doc page with all available statuses
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_InstanceState.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of posting, the current states are:

```
+--------+---------------+
|  Code  |     State     |
+--------+---------------+
|   0    |    pending    | 
|  16    |    running    |
|  32    | shutting-down | 
|  48    |  terminated   |
|  64    |   stopping    | 
|  80    |   stopped     |
+--------+---------------+
```

And the documentation can be found within the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud API reference under [InstanceStateType](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/index.html?ApiReference-ItemType-InstanceStateType.html)

The docs also mention a state code `272` which "*typically indicates a problem with the host running the instance*". They suggest trying a reboot in the first instance, and posting on the [EC2 forums](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/forum.jspa?forumID=30) if that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: This is so very relevant right now: http://33.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mdrbo2ilt21rbq6yxo1_500.gif

Answer (score 1):

The docs seem to have been moved, and I still can't find them.  Here are two more state codes

1. 64: stopping
2. 80: stopped